# PDOExecption - Receiving SQLSTATE[42000]: while changing MySQL to PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here is my code old code where everything worked fine:

```
if($tags != ""){
    $TagsSearch = " AND Tags LIKE '%".$tags."%'";
}

$requested_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;             
$r = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Blog` WHERE `Title`!='' $TagsSearch");
$d = mysql_fetch_row($r);
$product_count = $d[0];

$products_per_page = 10;


$page_count = ceil($product_count / $products_per_page);


$first_product_shown = ($requested_page - 1) * $products_per_page;
```

Here is my new code:

```
if($tags != ""){
    $TagsSearch = " AND Tags LIKE '%".$tags."%'";
}
$requested_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? intval($_GET['page']) : 1;             
$r = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Blog` WHERE `Title`!='' :TagsSearch");
$r->bindParam(':TagsSearch',$TagsSearch);
$d = $r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$product_count = $d[0];

$products_per_page = 10;


$page_count = ceil($product_count / $products_per_page);


$first_product_shown = ($requested_page - 1) * $products_per_page;
```

I receive the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1' in /var/www/html/blog.php:48 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/blog.php(48): PDO->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*)...') #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/blog.php on line 48
```

Where is my mistake and how can i fix it ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the value of $TagsSearch? I suppose it contains a question mark.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `$TagsSearch`? It looks from your provided code like it's SQL itself rather than being a normal string or integer. You cannot add this to a query with `bindParam` because the entire point of it is that it escapes SQL code.

After your update to the question, I think what you actually want to do is;

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Blog` WHERE `Title`!=''";
if($tags != ""){
    $sql .= " AND Tags LIKE :tags";
}
$r = $db->prepare($sql);
$tags_like = "%$tags%";
$r->bindParam(':tags', $tags_like);
```

Comment: @TonyStark, okay I've updated my answer which hopefully works for you.

Comment: Please see again my updated question because the `LIKE` statement must be included only when tags is not empty.

Comment: @TonyStark, okay I've re-updated my answer to account for that.

Comment: With your suggestion now i receive `Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in /var/www/html/blog.php on line 51` The line 51 is `$r->bindParam(':tags', "%$tags%");`.

Comment: @TonyStark Okay, I didn't realize that parameter was by-reference only. I've updated again to use a variable for that parameter.

Comment: You can use `bindVal()` with an expression. Also, the bind needs to be in `if` so you don't do it when you don't add the `AND` clause.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, okay I didn't know that. I thought it was valid to bind a parameter and then not use it but I could certainly be wrong about that.

Comment: @Barmar, yep I just re-read your comment and realized. That's good to know. I've always been using `bindVal` but I guess I've never written my code in such a way to require changing the value of a parameter after binding. Could certainly be useful in some cases though.

Answer (score 0):

You *cannot* include part of the query in a substitution parameter of a prepared statement. This is because the query is parsed *in its entirety* first, and *then* the substitution occurs at execution time. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php), second **NOTE:**, about halfway down the page.

One way to handle this would be to build the query string itself dynamically, like so:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Blog` WHERE `Title`!=''";
$args = array();
if (isset($tags) && '' != $tags)
{
  $query .= " AND Tags LIKE :tags";
  $args[':tags'] = "%" . $tags . "%"; // % must be in arg, not query
}
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($args);
```